# Multithreading and autorelease pool

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa, memory-management, grand-central-dispatch

As I'm mastering my skills with multithreading with GCD, I've come across some question. Suppose you have the following method:

```
    - (void)method {
    NSString *string= [NSString string]; //will be autoreleased

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    //very very lengthy operation...

    NSLog(@"%@", string); //is it safe?
    });
}
```

I'm wondering if this is correct, because I think I should have retained string before the block execution: in fact I fear that the event loop finishes and sends `string` an autorelease message before using `string` in the block. That would crash the program.

Am I right? Should I send a retain and a release message to `string` or this is the correct implementation?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @yes123 You're not giving arguments, expand on your point of view.

Comment: @yes123: anyone who wants to get something done, anyone who wants to get something done =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm wondering if this is correct, because I think I should have retained string before the block execution: in fact I fear that the event loop finishes and sends string an autorelease message before using string in the block.

Fear not:
A block captures the scope of the surrounding method/function in that it automatically `retain`s any object-variable that is used inside of the block. Be aware of that when you use `self` inside of a block, as this may greatly affect the lifetime of the object!

There is one exception to this rule, and that are variables declared as

```
__block SomeObjectPointerType variableName
```

### Update

Because there’s a new comment on this answer, I should probably add that things changed a little with the introduction of ARC:

Under ARC all object variables default to `__strong`, and **this holds for variables marked with `__block`** as well. If you want to avoid strong capturing of a variable in a block, you should define a local variable that is `__weak`.

### End Update

If you like to learn more about blocks, bbum gave an excellent session called *[Introducing Blocks and Grand Central Dispatch on iPhone](https://developer.apple.com/videos/archive/)* at WWDC 2010.

The "Block Details" section starts at 11:30.

Comment: If use __block, NSLog(@"%@", bself.string);  is it safe?

Answer (score -5):

The concern is; when an autorelease object releases?

```
NSString *myString= [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", stringVariable];
```

The myString depends upon stringVariable, whenever stringVariable releases the myString immediately releases.

```
NSString *myString= [NSString stringWithString: @"stringVariable"];
```

In practice it is observed the myString might be releases just after the completion of the method.

Now if you change your code and use **NSAutoReleasePool**

```
- (void)method {
    NSAutoreleasePool pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSString *string= [NSString string]; //will be autoreleased

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    //very very lengthy operation...

    // string will be released here
    [pool release];

    NSLog(@"%@", string); // it is not safe?
    });
}
```

**The autorelease objects released when the auto release pool releases in which they exists or when the object releases on which they depends.**

Now if you are using the method in a thread you should use auto release pool inside it.

```
- (void)method {
    NSAutoreleasePool pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

        // lengthy operations ...
    [pool release];
}
```

Comment: -1 there are quite a few errors in your answer: 1. There is no such method as `[NSString stringVariable]`. 2. `autorelease` **does not** release an object "just after the completion of the method". It releases the object, when the current `NSAutoreleasePool` is drained. If you didn't specify one yourself, that will be the one that the event-loop manages, so the object [lives until the end of the current iteration of the loop](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html). 3. You need to call `[pool drain]`.

Comment: "The myString depends upon stringVariable, whenever stringVariable releases the myString immediately releases." That is wrong as well! (And if it were true, the consequences would be at least _somewhat_ disastrous...) `+[NSString stringWithFormat:]` creates a new, autoreleased string by evaluating the format, thus creating a snapshot of the states of all the parameters that are passed to be substituted for the placeholders.

Comment: How did this answer get an upvote? Even after the edits, it still contains gross misinformation about string creation.

Comment: no offense, but look at the link in my first comment regarding autorelease-pools. (You might consider reading the [class reference for NSAutoreleasePool](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html) as well.) Regarding NSString, again: [Read the docs!](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) And for further reference on blocks, you might want to watch the WWDC session I linked to in my answer.

Comment: People, who cares about the NSString _false_ method? We're here to talk about autorelease pools.